# Elements operation in the corresponding position of a matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, filtering

I have two matrix

```
  x={{2, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 5}, {4, 5, 6}};
  probability={{0.09, 0.09, 0.12}, {0.09, 0.09, 0.12}, {0.12, 0.12, 0.16}};
```

Now I want to add up corresponding position probability.
for example,

$\Pr(x=3)=0.09+0.09$

$\Pr(x=4)=0.12+0.09+0.12$

I tried Position

```
   k = Position[x, 3];
  (*   {{1, 2}, {2, 1}}  *)
```

but they can not directly use

```
 x[[k]]
```

Which command should I use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 Total@Extract[probability, Position[x, 3]]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Total[Pick[probability, x, 3], 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
emp = EmpiricalDistribution[Flatten @ probability -> Flatten @ x]
p[n_] := Probability[z == n, z \[Distributed] emp]
```

E.g.

```
p[3]
```

> 0.18

```
p[4]
```

> 0.33